# Ubuntu 14.04, Wifi is disabled by Hardware Switch - Lenovo G50-80, Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, atheros

I have brought new Lenovo G50-80 Laptop and make it dual boot. My wifi works fine in Windows 8.1, but not working in Ubuntu 14.04, showing Wifi is disabled by hardware switch. When I do `rfkill*`, I got the following:

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes

2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

3: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have tried all the commands to enable it, but it only works for soft block. Any solution for it or there is any problem with the driver?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main possibilities:

First, your wifi could really be disabled by hardware switch. You may notice that there is a switch on your computer that has a *signal station* (meaning wifi) on it. If that is the problem, then you may have to turn it on. But you said that it works fine on Win 8, then it may not be this one.

Second, the system (Ubuntu) may not recognize the wifi card status, or the card may not be supported. A recommended way to solve this is to search drivers of your wifi card on Ubuntu.

Comment: My ubuntu use ath9k driver

Comment: @ASheikh Is the driver installed by the system originally or you installed it manually?

Comment: sorry for late reply...

Comment: Drivers are original. I have not installed any driver manually.

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop does not have a hardware wireless switch, then you can fixed it by

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

This will unlock wireless until you reboot.

If this helps, I suggest reporting a bug by running

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Follow the directions and post the bug link to comments. This laptop will be added to the quirk list.

Comment: this just solved the exact same issue on a debian squeeze running on a Lenovo G50-30 for a RTL8723BE

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called "ideapad_laptop" that prevents the wifi module to start.

1) blacklist this with:

```
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ideapad.conf
```

2) Prevents the WiFi card from automatically sleeping and halting connection

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

Comment: Hi, if you have found that duplicate answers answer different questions, then it is likely that some of the questions are duplicates of one. Instead of posting the same answer in multiple places, please flag the appropriate question(s) as (a) duplicate(s).